# Como mudar o tamanho de uma imageView no Android via código?

Tags: android

Tentei usar LayoutParams mas não funcionou, tentei `layoutParams.width = 80;` e não funcionou. Alguém sabe como fazer isso? Agradeço desde já.

No meu caso a imagem ficou muito grande eu precisava diminuir.

Meu código:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.verde));
```

Comment: Já que a sua imagem está na pasta *drawable* o indicado seria que ela já tivesse as dimensões desejadas. Assim não teria de usar processamento e memória em tempo de execução.

Comment: Se no entanto quer mesmo fazer isso em tempo de execução poste o código quando tentou usar `layoutParams` e explique o que quer dizer com "não funcionou".

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode tentar esse codigo:

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.dl_image);
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 120;
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Ou ainda pode usar duas propiedades do ImageView ainda no XML que sao

```
//Posiciona a imagem ao centro do elemento ImageView
android:scaleType="fitCenter"

//Redimensiona a imagem para que caiba toda no elemento ImageView
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Eu particularmente prefiro usar a segunda opção por ser mais pratico.

Att. Jeiferson